# Why does python allow to make different set of attributes for same class?

Tags: python, oop

I just started python, in java two different instances of same type have different values but it doesn't allow them to have different attributes. But,

```
class Point:
    pass

p1 = Point()
p1.x = 0
p1.y = 0
p2 = Point()
p2.z = 0
p2.w = 1355135
```

This code doesn't produce any error. So i am assuming it is a language feature. But i don't understand why python allows two instances of same type have different attributes?

How does it help in designing code?

Comment: What sort of "why" are you looking for?  The simple answer is "because Python is dynamic and almost anything can be changed at runtime", unlike Java.

Comment: hey, where is p1 defined at? :)

Comment: to change the definition you use inheritance why would someone allow definition to be dynamic?

Comment: Inheritance is by no mean a silver bullet - in fact it's very overrated in most mainstream "OO 101" litterature. When you think of it, inheritance is mainly a very restricted and tightly coupled form of composition/delegation, and quite a few more advanced OO literature advise to favor composition/delegation over inheritance (talking about implementation inheritance of course - type inheritance - the 'is a' relationship - is another topic). Remember that you don't always have the ability to select which concrete type will be instanciated by a library or framework...

Comment: @bhushanpatil: I assume you come from a Java / C++ background. There are quite a few programming languages feature that are builtin in dynamic OOPLs or functional languages that don't exist in this background   - anonymous functions, first order functions, closures, just to name a few - and seems useless until you learn how to use them - and finally realize that a good half of the Design Patterns are mainly workarounds for these lacking features. I spent a full year trying to forcefit static languages concepts into Python until I had the "aha" moment reading some popular Python app's code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Python is a dynamic language. A Python object is mostly a dict (containing instance attributes) + a reference to base classes (which are objects too) + a couple hooks looking class attributes on the base classes when they don't exist in the instance's dict. FWIW you can even change an object's type at runtime if you want.

How does it helps design code ? Well, having the ability to dynamically add / replace arbitrary instance and class attributes (including methods) at runtime makes life much much easier for some kind of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Because Python is a dynamic language.

JavaScript e.g. would do the same 
(not that JavaScript is very similar to Python).

"How does it help in designing code?"
It allows the programmer more freedom which the compiler in a static 
language takes away in return for some security or sense of security.
But this is subjective in general, some prefer static languages, 
others prefer dynamic ones.

Answer (score 1):

> How does it help in designing code?

It doesn't. It's the price we pay for having a fully dynamic class system. That means not only do we not have to declare the members separately somewhere, we can delegate parts of the intialization to helper methods or decorators, for example. Or even more versatile meta programming can be done, at run time, without need for a separate language.